# Adding batteries in series but with reversed terminals

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, voltage, batteries

So I have a bit of an interesting question. My physics professor showed me this diagram:

[image]

And he asked us all what the potential difference, or voltage, was. Now, from my understanding these batteries are not in series. To be in series the negative terminal of one battery must touch the positive terminal of the next battery. In this manner, all the batteries are "switched."

But why wouldn't this work? I know it shouldn't, and the voltage I'm guessing is zero, but why? I understand voltage is basically charge separation, but that's still achieved here.

Comment: The batteries *are* in series. Series connection is not restricted to the polarity of batteries. Resistors don't even have polarities, but you can say they are connected in series (assuming they're actually in series, i.e.one after the other without any element in a node between them.)

Answer (score 1):

This configuration is okay actually. It works but doesn't give the maximum voltage that can be achieved with the 3 batteries.

Draw the batteries (cells) as they were in a circuit diagram. And you'll see when you calculate the total voltage that you have to subtract the voltage of the cell in reverse. (Please forgive my very crude picture drawn in MS Paint)

[image]

$V_t = 3V -1V +3V$

In that way, the resultant voltage comes out to be, $5V$!

You'll get $7V$ if they were connected in the correct manner.

And for the record, the batteries are in series. The polarity of one cell is reversed that's all.

Answer (score 0):

The given connection of three batteries will work but at lower terminal (output) voltage $V_t$ but not zero as you guess (Given connection of batteries is figure below).
[image]

Applying Kirchhoff's Voltage Law for closed circuit, the terminal voltage $V_{t}$ is given as follows
$$V_{t}-3+1-3=0$$
$$V_t=5\mathrm{V}$$

But for getting the maximum terminal voltage $(V_t)_{max}$,  we need to reverse the connections of $1\mathrm{V}$ battery to get a correct series connection of three batteries (as shown in figure below)

[image]

Applying Kirchhoff's Voltage Law for closed circuit, the maximum terminal voltage $(V_t)_{max}$ in corrected series connection is given as follows
$$(V_t)_{max}-3-1-3=0$$
$$(V_t)_{max}=7\mathrm{V}$$

Answer (score 0):

I would try to explain this question in a bit different manner but I think this one's easy to understand (at least for me).

The battery always creates a potential difference across its terminals whatever be the condition. This statement might also be stated in this manner - The battery increments the voltage at its negative terminal by $V$ volts to the positive terminal.

Thus for example in the below circuit, the $V_A$ volts at A would become, at B:-

[image]

$$V_B = V_A +V$$

And also, if the terminals of the battery are reversed in the above circuit (points A and B remaining the same) then the potential difference will be still $V$. Hence, $$V_B = V_A - V$$(Battery needs to maintain the potential difference of $V$ volts)

And now coming to the question, I would convert the given figure to a circuit diagram.

[image]

Let the potential at A be $V_A$. Then the potential at B would become $$V_B = V_A + 3V$$. And moving further potential at C would become $$V_C = V_B  -1V = V_A + 3V - 1V = V_A + 2V$$(Note here that there was potential drop as the battery was placed the opposite way). And at last the potential at D will be $$V_D = V_C +3V = V_A +2V + 3V = V_A + 5V$$
Thus the potential difference across this setup of batteries will be $$∆V = V_D - V_A= V_A+5V - V_A= 5V$$